# How to turn a cube to a face

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Regardless of the rotation of the cube, by pressing the button, the cube should rotate to the face.

Example:

[image]

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;

public class CubeDoTweenController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Quaternion targetRotation;


    private void Awake()
    {
        targetRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Vector3.right);
            transform.DORotateQuaternion(targetRotation, 1f);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Vector3.forward);
            transform.DORotateQuaternion(targetRotation, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

After a couple of turns, the old cube starts to rotate. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why not simply `*= Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);` and `*= Quaternion.Euler(0,0,90);` ? Do you also want to move it like in the image?

Comment: Does the code works without tweens ? I mean, with immediate rotation for debug

Comment: I used `*= Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);` and `*= Quaternion.Euler(0,0,90);` and it's don't work too. No, I do not want to move box, just rotate. I also try to rotate box without DoTween, but decided to use DoTween for the test, as it turned out, the result did not change

Comment: another very important thing is that each face of the cube has its own color!!!

Comment: So if I sum it up, you start the game, you press a key, your cube turns.
After some rotation of your cube, it appears the rotation has a strange offset, is this it or do I missed something ?

Comment: Not really. I will give an example. If you start the game and press W, then the cube will flip forward as it should, but if you start the game and press D twice and then press W, the cube will flip back. The rotation of the cube is, as it were, calculated in local coordinates, and I expect that it will be calculated in global @ThomasFinet

Comment: i tried using `Transform.RotateAround(...)` and everything works as it should but entails a lot of unwanted operations. So i gave up on this solution

Comment: Man...why is it so hard XD have you tried the `DOLocalRotate(Vector3 to, float duration, RotateMode mode)
` method from DoTween ?

Comment: Apparently it's difficult for me to convey my message in English. I want to rotate an object relative to global coordinates, if the usual rotation did not help me with this, then how will local rotation help me with this? @ThomasFinet

Comment: what if you use `targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Vector3.right) * targetRotation;` ?

Comment: it worked! I will try to figure out why. Thanks a lot to everyone who tried to help @Ruzihm

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have the solution to your problem... Instead of using `Vectro3` axis, try to use your `transform` axis like so:

`transform.rotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, transform.forward);`

The thing is that what does `Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3 from, Vector3 to)` is calculating the angle between `from` and `to`. Then you apply this rotation on your transform which is local.

For exemple
`Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Vector3.right);`
generate a rotation of 90 degrees around z axis.

Applied two times on your game object, x axis equals -x axis

`Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Vector3.forward);`
generate a rotation of 90 degrees around x axis.

But now, as your x axis equals -x axis, it is like the rotation around x has been inverted but if you follow the rotation of your cube, everything is fine.

Using local axis will then follow the rotation of your cube and do as your cube rotates in world space

Comment: `Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, Vector3.right)` generates a rotation around the z axis.

Comment: Also, `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, transform.forward);` doesn't rotate in world space. That's a rotation local to `transform`.